# Почему высота меню на 5px больше, чем его содержимое (отступы нигде не задаются). Bootstrap 3. Navbar

Tags: css, вёрстка, bootstrap

Задача, понять причины происходящего. Вопрос появился в результате попытки повторить верстку следующей страницы

https://www.free-css.com/assets/files/free-css-templates/preview/page196/conquer/

Заметил странную особенность, что высота меню (#tmNavbar) на 5px больше, чем высота его потомка (ul-элемента с классами nav navbar-nav) при ширине браузера больше 768px. Через инспектор не смог найти никаких стилей, задающих отступ, который мог увеличить высоту меню. Там висит clearfix, но, как я понимаю, он не должен производить такого эффекта.

Почему высота меню больше, чем его содержимое на 5px?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это из-за `display: inline-block` у `ul`. Исправить можно добавив `vertical-align: middle`

Comment: Ок, стало понятнее, но все-таки не до конца. Где прочитать подробнее про эту магию строчных и строчно-блочных элементов?

Comment: @IliaEliseev по умолчанию `inline-block` элементы выравниваются по базовой линии, и эта базовая линия не совпадает с геометрическим центром

Answer (score 0):

есть вероятность, что это особенность браузера
можно попробовать:
1) поставить normalize.css
2) поставить у li display: block
3) добавить у html box-sizing: content-box

Comment: Проблема не в том, чтобы повторить. Повторить можно и тупо через высоту меню, и через отступы. Проблема, понять такое поведение в данном примере